# jqMath comma (,) not displayed inside \table

Tags: jqmath

I am using jQmath and its perfectly working in both mobile and desktop for all equations

For displaying a function below with comma separated between a(1-cos2x),b inside table e.g. below:

```
$f(x) = \{\table   a(1-cos2x), \, b; x-c, \, d$
```

In the above equation displaying of comma (,) is missing even after using escape by \ character.

Anyone facing similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

`\,` produces a space, like in TeX. Use grouping instead of quoting: `{,}` produces a comma inside a table.